# In R, how can I extend generic methods from one package in another?

Tags: r, generics, package

I have a package `PackageA` with a generic function:

```
#' doWork
#' 
#' Do some work!
#'
#' @export
setGeneric(
    "doWork", 
    function(x) {

        standardGeneric("doWork")
    })

setMethod(
    "doWork", 
    signature = c("numeric"), 
    definition = function(x) {

        x == 10 # Some logic... 
    }
```

In `PackageB`, which depends on `PackageA`, I would like to add more methods to `doWork`:

```
#' @import PackageA
setMethod(
    "doWork", 
    signature = c("character"), 
    definition = function(x) {

        length(x) == 1 && x == "10" # Some more logic... 
    }
```

This works. However, it means that the user of `PackageB` must also `library(PackageA)`.

This fails:

```
library(PackageB)

doWork("10") # Fails!
```

This works:

```
library(PackageA)
library(PackageB)

doWork("10")
```

I would like to use the generic from `PackageA` in `PackageB`, but not require `PackageA` to be loaded to use just the methods in `PackageB`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually documented, but it's not very clear; see section `1.5.6` of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf).

The trick is to import the generic from `PackageA` and then re-export it from `PackageB`. Using `roxygen` annotations, this looks like:

```
#' @importMethodsFrom PackageA doWork
#' @export 
setMethod(
    "doWork", 
    signature = c("character"), 
    definition = function(x) {

        length(x) == 1 && x == "10" # Some more logic... 
    })
```

When you call `devtools::document()`, this will fail unless you have first loaded `PackageA` (call `library(PackageA)`).

However, once built, `PackageA` is not required:

```
> library(PackageB)
> showMethods("doWork")
Function: doWork (package PackageA)
x="character"
x="numeric"
```

For reference, the auto-generated `NAMESPACE` file looks like:

```
exportMethods(doWork)
importMethodsFrom(PackageA, doWork)
```

This method produces no warnings about naming conflicts and so on, so it seems to be "kosher".

Comment: This answer worked for me, and is in accordance to the R Extension Manual.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work for me, but I don't see it documented so I wouldn't necessarily assume it is kosher.  `pckgA`:

```
#' @export

setGeneric("doWork", function(x) standardGeneric("doWork"))
setMethod("doWork", signature = "numeric", function(x) x == 11)
```

and `pckgB`:

```
#' @export
#' @import pckgA

setGeneric("doWork", getGeneric("doWork", package="pckgA"))
setMethod("doWork", "character", function(x) identical(x, "10"))
```

The main trick was to import and re-export `doWork` from `pckgA` in `pckgB`.  Then starting with a clean R session:

```
library(pckgB)
doWork("10")
# [1] TRUE
doWork("11")
# [1] FALSE
doWork(11)
# [1] TRUE
library(pckgA)
doWork(11)
# [1] TRUE
doWork("10")
# [1] TRUE
```

You may need to completely clear your workspace (including hidden objects) to get rid of any prior method definitions for this to actually take effect properly.

Comment: My roxygen doesn't seem to like that: "Failure in roxygen block ... .Data is not a slot in class environment"

Comment: I'll mark this is the solution because it *works*, but it doesn't seem like The Right Way to do it.